# Python lxml etree.tostring() returns empty string running on mod_wsgi

Tags: python, wsgi

I have Python 2.7.8 on CentOS 6.8 where my server is built upon Apache2 + WSGI. My application should handle the date received with http POST, then create an instruction based on XML template gotten from local .xml file. Finally, it must send xml instruction back with 200 OK response. The logic of the application is seems working Ok and I may see my updated xml tree with:

```
print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration-True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

The issue appears to be happened at next row of my code where I'm doing the same operation but trying assign the output to variable:

```
xml_body = etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration-True, encoding='UTF-8')
```

print xml_body

The output is empty string, thus my application then returns nothing back to Apache.

My environment info may be helpful:

```
==For bug report ===
Python              : sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
lxml.etree          : (3, 6, 4, 0)
libxml used         : (2, 7, 6)
libxml compiled     : (2, 9, 4)
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 26)
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 29)
```

It looks similar to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1556625)   However, the author mentioned it doesn't work at all. There is another one [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599442/lxml-tostring-returns-blank-string-in-flask-running-on-mod-wsgi) which contains similar issue, but it still isn't resolved.
I've checked out I might successfully play the same scenario in Python cli:

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, May 15 2016, 12:46:09) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> foo = etree.Element('foo')
>>> foo
<Element foo at 0x7f5097c4fc20>
>>> foo.tag
'foo'
>>> foo.text = 'barrisimo'

>>> xmlb = etree.tostring(foo, pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True, encoding='UTF-8')
>>> print xmlb
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<foo>barrisimo</foo>1
```

Have somebody come across the same issue ever? I'm in dead end and I'd be appreciated for any help, ideas or helpful links.

Comment: it seems there is problem with `tostring()` in `mod_wsgi` and still no solution.

Comment: Can you fix your code snippet to what you actually have. That isn't even valid Python. You can't assign the result of using ``print`` to a variable as you have in ``xml_body = print etree.tostring(...)``.

Comment: Did you heed the advice in the linked post where it talks about using an older version of libxml and libxslt than what lxml was originally compiled for? Your case seems to match exactly that scenario and as mentioned that can cause problems. Did you ensure you upgraded system packages for the libraries?

Comment: thanks for you had me pointed out the mistake - I've fixed it. Concerning the case that I've mentioned - there is one thing bother me: in the case they mentioned that it didn't worked at all even over Python cli. In my case - it works over cli, it even works within the script (at least I'm obtaining the tree with print() ), while it doesn't assign the tree neither as string nor as a list if I use tostringlist(). However. I suppose the mismatch of library releases might be a cause of the problem. But what does mean "used" and "compiled" libxslt and how to do them match?

Comment: Are you using system packages for lxml or did you ``pip install`` it yourself? If a system package, it means when that system package was compiled by the maintainers of the package, it had newer versions of the libraries on the system than you have. You need to use your system packaging system to update the packages for the libraries to the latest. Ensure you have done the same for lxml Python package if using a packaged version.

Comment: I would like to add that I'm getting the same bug behaviour trying to output an XML string in a Blender (the 3d graphics program) Python script. I `pip install`ed lxml for Blender's bundled Python distribution.

Answer (score 3):

Have the same issue.

My test file `test.py`:

```
from lxml import etree


def application(env, start_response):
    foo = etree.Element("foo")
    foo.text = "bar"
    out = etree.tostring(foo)

    print('-------------')
    print(foo)
    print('=============')
    print(out)
    print('-------------')

    if start_response:
        start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])

    return [b"TEST"]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application(None, None)
```

When run in cli mode:

```
python test.py
```

It returns:

```
-------------
<Element foo at 0x7f5b80671488>
=============
<foo>bar</foo>
-------------
```

But if I run in wsgi mode, it returns None:

```
uwsgi --http :9090 --wsgi-file test.py
```

Then receive

```
-------------
<Element foo at 0x7f8f84aa7638>
=============

-------------
```

Pip freeze:

```
lxml==3.7.2
uWSGI==2.0.14
```

Lib versions:

```
libxml used         : (2, 9, 3)
libxml compiled     : (2, 9, 3)
libxslt used        : (1, 1, 29)
libxslt compiled    : (1, 1, 29)
```

Core reason of issue is unknown, but problem was solved by removing package `libxml2-dev` and reinstalling uwsgi:

```
aptitude remove libxml2-dev
pip uninstall uwsgi
pip install --no-cache-dir uwsgi
```

So, somehow package libxml2-dev is not compatible with uwsgi.

Answer (score 2):

In case the **`libxml`** version at runtime is different from the compiled version it means there are more than one `libxml` version installed in your system:

```
libxml used         : (2, 7, 8)
libxml compiled     : (2, 9, 3)
```

In my case `mod_php5` was the problem. I have fixed this by re-compiling apache without PHP. It turns out PHP was using `libxml` version 2.7.8 and the python interpreter used in `mod_wsgi` was pointing to the same `xmllib` instead of using the python one.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 6 and Python 2.7 are quite old now. So, I think the best solution is to install an old version of lxml: lxml < 3.6 solve this issue (for instance [lxml 3.5.0](https://lxml.de/3.5/)).

Using [Andrey Kolpakov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1706096/andrey-kolpakov) [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598060/1513933), the wsgi logs shows:

```
[Fri Jul 03 14:49:25 2020] [error] -------------
[Fri Jul 03 14:49:25 2020] [error] <Element foo at 0x7faa741cb200>
[Fri Jul 03 14:49:25 2020] [error] =============
[Fri Jul 03 14:49:25 2020] [error] <foo>bar</foo>
[Fri Jul 03 14:49:25 2020] [error] -------------
```