# django use spyne lib on apache server response no content

Tags: django, wsgi, spyne

I have developed a web service, using `spyne.protocol.soap.soap11`
when running In Django command (python manage runserver), it works as expected:

1.I can get wsdl file from $url?wsdl

2.call a web service and get response

but when  deployed in apache server, it response $url?wsdl with status 200 OK but no content:

```
Connection →close
Content-Length →0
Content-Type →text/xml; charset=utf-8
Date →Mon, 16 Oct 2017 02:22:08 GMT
Server →Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
```

and I can also call a web service, and the server does what I want(insert a data to the database) but apache server response no content.

**Note: All above running on the same machine, same python**

I have searched in google and StackOverflow, but there are no similar questions.

```
1 class AbnormalService(ServiceBase):
2 @rpc(Unicode, Unicode, Integer, Integer, Integer, _returns=Unicode)
3 def abnormal(ctx, username, password, locationID, abnormalID, smallAbnormalID):
4    try:
5        AbnormalRecord.objects.create(location_id=locationID, abnormal_id=abnormalID, smallAbnormal_id=smallAbnormalID)
6   except Exception as ex:
7        return str(ex)
8   return "OK"
```

This is my spyne web service view. And line 5 did excuted on apache server(Database added a line). And It is supposed to responding like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soap11env:Envelope xmlns:soap11env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="spyne.examples.django">
<soap11env:Body>
    <tns:abnormalResponse>
        <tns:abnormalResult>OK</tns:abnormalResult>
    </tns:abnormalResponse>
</soap11env:Body>
</soap11env:Envelope>
```

**But the respons with header Content-Length:0, and web service did excuted**
I had try add  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL} to httpd.conf, nothing changed.
My django setting:
urls:

```
url(r'^uploadrecords', DjangoView.as_view(
    services=[views.AbnormalService], tns='spyne.examples.django',
        in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
        out_protocol=Soap11(),
        cache_wsdl=False)),
    url(r'^api/', DjangoView.as_view(application=views.app)),`<br>

views:

    class AbnormalService(ServiceBase):
    @rpc(Unicode, Unicode, Integer, Integer, Integer, _returns=Unicode)
    def abnormal(ctx, username, password, locationID, abnormalID, smallAbnormalID):
        try:
            AbnormalRecord.objects.create(location_id=locationID, abnormal_id=abnormalID, smallAbnormal_id=smallAbnormalID)
        except Exception as ex:
            return str(ex)
        return "OK"

    app = Application([AbnormalService],
    'spyne.examples.django',
    in_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    out_protocol=Soap11(validator='lxml'),
    )
    abnormal_service = csrf_exempt(DjangoApplication(app))
```

settings:

```
   WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIPythonPath /var/www/html/kanban
    Listen 9000
    <VirtualHost *:9000>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/kanban/kanban">
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
</Directory>



WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/kanban/kanban/wsgi.py

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog logs/django_log
    CustomLog logs/django_custom_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using mod_wsgi? You don't explicitly mention it, but your separate labels on question of ``wsgi`` and ``mod`` suggest you might. If using mod_wsgi, how have you configured it? Also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api and try that suggested config. An empty response may suggest the process is crashing and that setting can help.

Comment: yes, i use mod_wsgi, and the website work fine for half a year. recently i add webservice use spyne. so I think mod_wsgi configuration is ok.<br>

Comment: the diffrence between apache server and django command is it  responses no  xml content on apache server but the webservice can be called on both situation

Comment: the server status is 200,  there is no error

Comment: So try ``WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}`` as explained in the link. The lxml library, if being used, can crash when used in Python sub interpreters. That directive forces the use of the main interpreter context, like what would happen if using Python from the command line.

Comment: Graham Dumpleton, I did try WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}, not working.

Comment: You need to provide then what version of mod_wsgi you are using and what your mod_wsgi configuration is so can see how you have set it up. Also ensure Apache has ``LogLevel info`` at least and not just ``LogLevel warn``. Check Apache error logs for any process restarts of mod_wsgi daemon mode processes if using daemon mode, or other messages about process crashes.

Comment: mod_wsgi 4.5.2  apache 2.2.15  python 3.4.3  spyne 2.12.14 lxml 4.0.0 this a apache log: 10.19.6.107 - - [16/Oct/2017:16:37:55 +0800] "GET /screen/uploadrecords?wsdl HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: That is the Apache access log. More interest in what is in the Apache error log at the time of the request.

Comment: If I change out_protocol  from Soap11() to JsonDocument(), Apache server now can response Json format result "OK". I think spyne  Soap11 need some extra configuration, because it return "xml" format.Apache do not get error. I set tail -f django_log(the error output file).

Comment: Now the fault i found is  in lxml lib. I made a test, if use lxml in a plain django view,  "return HttpResponse(str(etree.tostring(root)))"  in apache2.2 the return is b'' , in django command mode is the result i needs. I did add WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}.

Comment: Ensure you have the latest lxml package version installed.

Comment: The lxml version is 4.1.0, the latest package. **My test view work fine in python manage runserver.  But in apache2 return empty without error**  .def lxmltest(request):
    from lxml import etree
    root = etree.Element("root")
    child = etree.SubElement(root,"child")
    child.text = "miemie"
    return HttpResponse(str(etree.tostring(child)))

Comment: Suggest you use daemon mode of mod_wsgi (which is the preferred mode anyway) and then ensure setting lang/locale to a sane value. http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/setting-lang-and-lcall-when-using.html  http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/configuration-guidelines.html#defining-process-groups

Comment: There is a similar issue [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051305/python-lxml-etree-tostring-returns-empty-string-running-on-mod-wsgi). I have set daemon model, but also not working. I choose to use uwsgi with nginx,  this time the output is correct. @GrahamDumpleton

Comment: Were you using PHP in the same Apache? It has been a while since I have seen one of the issues mentioned in that other link whereby PHP was pulling in a different lxml library. If you weren't using PHP for anything but had it loaded into Apache, you could ensure you disable it.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton You are right. After disable php the response is OK. Thanks a lot.